Cannot load `httpuv` package: httpuv.dll load failed
I am trying to load the httpuv package after installing it in a fresh R 4.4.1 session without success (using install.packages("httpuv")). Once installed, I try to load it using library(httpuv) and the following error pops up:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘httpuv’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/js/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4/httpuv/libs/x64/httpuv.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  No se encontró el proceso especificado.

The error suggests that the .dll does not exist, but when I browse that location the .dll is there. Also, I can load other installed packages (e.g., dplyr) and I checked that rtools is installed with pkgbuild::find_rtools().
My session info:
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Mexico.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Mexico.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Mexico.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Mexico.1252    

time zone: Etc/GMT+6
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.4.1    magrittr_2.0.3   
 [3] R6_2.5.1          cli_3.6.3        
 [5] promises_1.3.0    later_1.3.2      
 [7] tools_4.4.1       rstudioapi_0.16.0
 [9] Rcpp_1.0.13       rlang_1.1.4

